# How to use $in to get all data in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I use `$in` for my query in mongo, I write something likes

```
var array = returnArrayFromMe() // this will return an array ['a', 'b']
```

And then

```
//Stuff
$in: ['$something', array],
```

But sometimes, `returnArrayFromMe` return `[]`.
What i want is, if `array = []`, my query will return all data.
How can i do that with `$in`?.
I know we can do this with an `if else` 
But, is there anyway to get all if `array = []` without `if else`?

Comment: Can you share more code, how you are forming query? Are you using projection or query?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I do not think this is a good practice. Basically you are including business logic in the data layer ("if there are no filters present select everything"). This should not be done here.

If even so you would like to do it this way and you are using aggregation you could probably use the $cond (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator to get his done. Even so it would not be a good practice as you would have to project on of the two lists, the full list of "$something" or the filtered one returned by you (using the $cond to test whether your list is empty). And use the return from this projection to filter out the results.

How I was able to help.